# Finding an example to fit the definition of basic slicing in numpy's reference

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Basic slicing always returns a `view` according to [Numpy's reference](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing), and its more detailed definition is copied below:

> Basic slicing extends Python’s basic concept of slicing to N
> dimensions. Basic slicing occurs when obj is a slice object
> (constructed by start:stop:step notation inside of brackets), an
> integer, or **a tuple of  slice objects and integers**. Ellipsis and
> newaxis objects can be interspersed with these as well.

What I concern is the bold part. I tried to find an example to fit the definition of the bold part but to no avail. Failed examples are shown below:

```
import numpy as np

y = np.array(
    [ [f"y[{r},{c}]" for c in range(5)]
    for r in range(6)]
)

def check_is_view(arr1, arr2):
    try:
        if arr2.base is arr1:
            return True
        elif np.may_share_memory(arr1, arr2):
            return True
        return False
    except AttributeError:
        return False

## tuples of integers
print("print(y[(0,1), (3,4)]):")
print(check_is_view(y, y[(0,1), (3,4)])) #return False which means not a view

## a slice object  + a tuple of integers    
print("print(y[slice(0,2), (3,4)]:")
print(check_is_view(y, y[slice(0,2), (3,4)])) #return False which means not a view
```

What does the bold part mean? What are the examples for the bold part?

Comment: The code you have works fine if you pass it arrays.         
 a =np.array((1,2))
b = a[1:1]
print(check_is_view(a,b))

Comment: @ggorlen Overlook `y`. Updated.

Comment: `x[1, 2:6, np.newaxis]` is the equivalent of `x[(1, slice(2,6), np.newaxis)]`.  In python it's the comma that makes a tuple, the `()` just add clarity.

Comment: @hpaulj Okay, this explains the meaning of "a tuple of slice objects and integers" there, if what you contend is really true.  Super confusing when I just read the text.